# Can't convert image to other colorspace given with correct path and extension in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I know that there are a lot of questions in this topic but I did not find the answer to my problem. Consider a folder containing images of scanned pdf files (created with pdf2image). Now I want to convert them to grayscale. But for some of the images I am getting the following error message:

```
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

- I **specified the absolute path** to the files **with** the **correct extension** (file names are good because they are extracted with os and glob modules). It works for a proportion of the images, but not for all of them. For some reason they are read as empty frames while I can open them in any image viewer application.
- I ****checked for corrupt** images** but did not find one.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Here are my functions:

```
def convert_from_folder_to_images(input_pdfs_path, output_path):

    if output_path is None:
        output_path = input_pdfs_path
    else:
        output_path = output_path

    list_of_pdfs = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(input_pdfs_path + "/*.pdf")]

    for i in range(len(list_of_pdfs)):
        file_name = list_of_pdfs[i].split(".")[0]
        pages = convert_from_path(input_pdfs_path + "/" + list_of_pdfs[i], poppler_path = 
        r"C:\Users\username\poppler-0.68.0\bin")
    for j in range(len(pages)):
        pages[j].save(output_path + "/" + file_name + "_" + str(j) + ".jpg")

def convert_to_grayscale(input_images_path, output_path): 

    if output_path is None:
        output_path = input_images_path
    else:
        output_path = output_path

    list_of_images = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(input_images_path + "/*.jpg")]

    for i in range(len(list_of_images)):
        file_name = list_of_images[i].split(".")[0]
        image = cv2.imread(input_images_path + "/" + list_of_images[i])
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
        cv2.imwrite(output_path + "/" + file_name + "_" + str(i) + "_" + "gray" + ".jpg", gray)
```

and the function call:

```
    input_raw_images_path = r"C:\Users\username\projects\project\pdf-images"
    output_grayscale_images_path = r"C:\Users\username\projects\project\grayscale-images"
    convert_to_grayscale(input_raw_images_path, output_grayscale_images_path)
```

Comment: @AcaNg I have checked their sizes. For example there is an image with size of 442KB and it has contents in it. I can open this image with an image viewer. But it is read as an empty image by opencv.

Comment: try adding this to `convert_to_grayscale()`, in the for loop, above the `cv2.cvtColor()` line: `print(file_name, image.shape)` and run again. what is your output ?

Comment: @AcaNg The output is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'"

Comment: it means that no file found, or empty file is read. how did you call `convert_from_folder_to_images()` ?

Comment: @AcaNg `convert_from_folder_to_images(input_path, output_path)` where `input_path = r"C:\Users\username\input_pdfs"` and `output_path = r"C:\Users\username\projects\project\grayscale-images"`

Comment: do any of your file names (and your username) have non-ascii character ?

Comment: btw, the outputs of `convert_from_folder_to_images()` are saved in `grayscale-images` while input of `convert_to_grayscale()` is `pdf-images`

Comment: At the first glance the file names contain ascii characters (they contain letters from hungarian alphabet, underscore, and numbers), but when I try `print("string".isascii())` it returns False in case of images read as empty. But those images which are read correctly contain the same type of characters in their filename. But you helped me a lot with this idea and thank you very much. :-) Now I'll just figure out how to make them ascii. If you post your comment into answer I will mark it as the perfect answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error was that some filenames contained nonascii characters as @AcaNg suggested in the comments. So I wrote a function to resolve this problem. It works well for me. I hope it will help others in the future.

```
def filename_corrector(input_path):
    list_of_files = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(input_path + 
                    "/*.jpg")]
    list_of_filenames = [x.split(".")[0] for x in list_of_files]

    ascii_filenames = []
    nonascii_filenames = []

    for i in range(len(list_of_filenames)):
        if list_of_filenames[i].isascii() == True:
            ascii_filenames.append(list_of_filenames[i])
        else:
            nonascii_filenames.append(list_of_filenames[i])

    for i in range(len(nonascii_filenames)):
        file_name = nonascii_filenames[i].encode("ascii", "ignore")
        os.rename(input_path + "/" + nonascii_filenames[i] + ".jpg", input_path 
        + "/" + str(file_name) + ".jpg")
```